# RTL Issue with Gizmox VisualWebGUI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-web-gui

I had a .NET 3.5 web application in which I had used `Gizmox VisualWebGUI` in it

After a year I needed toadd some new feature to it, I installed `WebGUI` again as trial (30 days full functionality) and implement my change sets.

When I browsed the project with Internet explorer (or any other browser) everything was working great except **RTL** Actually everything displayed in LTR manner. I checked everything and I couldn't find what's happened.

Any idea is appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Do you set all of the `RightToLeft` attributes in properties window?

For the window, panel, label and etc?

You also need to check the alignment. In addition may be something is going wrong with your build process